# SQL Server database with Latin1 codepage shows Japanese Chars as "?"

Tags: sql-server-2005, unicode, utf-8, codepages, latin1

Three questions with the following scenario:

- SQL Server 2005 production db with a Latin1 codepage and showing "?" for invalid chars in Management Studio.
- SomeCompanyApp client as a service that populates the data from servers and workstations.
- SomeCompanyApp management console that shows "?" for Asian characters.

Since this is a prod db I will not write to it.

I don't know if the client app that is storing the data in the database is actually storing it correctly as Unicode and it simply doesn't show because they are using Latin1 for the console.

**Q1:** As I understand it, SQL Server stores nvarchar text as Unicode regardless of the codepage or am I completely wrong and if the codepage is Latin1 then everything that is not in that codepage gets converted to "?".

**Q2:** Is it the same with a text column?

**Q3:** Is there a way using SQL Server Management Studio or Visual Studio and some code (don't care which language :)) to query the db and show me if the chars really do show up as Japanese, Chinese, Korean, etc.?

My final goal is to extract data from the db and store it in another db using UTF-8 to show Japanese and other Asian chars as what they are in my own client webapp.  **I will settle for an answer to Q3.**  I can code in several languages and at the very least understand some others but I'm just not knowledgeable enough about Unicode.  In case you want to know my webapp will be using pyodbc and cassandra but for these questions that doesn't matter.

Comment: My understanding about nvarchar is also on your lines. Are you able to use direct `insert` statement in Management Studio and store Japanese characters in these columns?

Comment: Production db, I dont want to do anything but read from it.  Besides since nvarchar per previous answer does store the unicode info then it depends on what the application that writes to it does with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inserting into an NVARCHAR column in SSMS, you need to make absolutely sure you're prefixing your string with a `N`:

This will **NOT** work:

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(NVarcharColumn) VALUES('Some Text with Special Char')
```

SQL Server will interpret your string in the `VALUES(..)` as VARCHAR and thus strip off any special characters.

You need **this**:

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(NVarcharColumn) VALUES(N'Some Text with Special Char')
```

Prefixing your text literal with an `N'..'` tells SQL Server to treat this as NVARCHAR all the way.

Does this help you solve your Q3 ??

Comment: It helps me understand how it works, basically that I was correctly thinking in Q1 that is does store it in Unicode.  Since I have no idea how the current service is storing data in nvarchar Q3 is more about verifying what did happen, did they use N'' or simply insert after encoding it to Latin1 externally.  Thank you!

Comment: Since no one else has answered I will just leave it as is since I'm putting this project in the back burner.  I will simply mark you as the answer.